# Geometric Setting?

Tags: statistics

Is this a geometric setting: Record the number of times a player makes both shots in a one-and-one foul-shooting situation.  (In this situation, you get to attempt a second shot only if you *make* your first shot.)

I said "No because the events aren't independent.  You only get to the second shot if you succeed on the first one."

^Do you think that's a correct answer?

Comment: Yes, because in case the first shot is missed there is no chance to make the second, so the probability is $0$ in this case.

Comment: If the question says *"Record the number..."* and your answer is *"No, because..."* that sounds like an obviously incorrect answer. A correct answer would involve a record of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

My question was answered by [Peter](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1129430/geometric-setting#comment2305237_1129430):

> Yes, because in case the first shot is missed there is no chance to make the second, so the probability is $0$ in this case.